# Looking for numerical/multimedia/signal_processing benchmarks in C (maybe c++)

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, benchmarking

I am working on custom instruction selection algorithms for fgpas softcore, and I need some C code to test my system.

My requirement are:

- Oriented toward heavy number crunching : numerical/multimedia/signal_processing
- Written in C (prefered) or C++ (or anything llvm can compile)
- Platform agnostic (no inline assembly etc...)

I have found [Mibench 1](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/mibench/) and 2 , but it seems a bit outdated.

Does anyone have any other links?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could adapt something from CPU2006's FP components.  From http://www.spec.org/cpu2006/Docs/:

```
410.bwaves  Fortran Fluid Dynamics
416.gamess  Fortran Quantum Chemistry
433.milc    C   Physics: Quantum Chromodynamics
434.zeusmp  Fortran Physics / CFD
435.gromacs C/Fortran   Biochemistry/Molecular Dynamics
436.cactusADM   C/Fortran   Physics / General Relativity
437.leslie3d    Fortran Fluid Dynamics
444.namd    C++ Biology / Molecular Dynamics
447.dealII  C++ Finite Element Analysis
450.soplex  C++ Linear Programming, Optimization
453.povray  C++ Image Ray-tracing
454.calculix    C/Fortran   Structural Mechanics
459.GemsFDTD    Fortran Computational Electromagnetics
465.tonto   Fortran Quantum Chemistry
470.lbm C   Fluid Dynamics
481.wrf C/Fortran   Weather Prediction
482.sphinx3 C   Speech recognition
```

Some of these take a huge amount of RAM.  You might have to modify the working set, but the good news is source is available.